# Converting IntegerField to Int or Automated Testing ensuring value > 0

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models

I am trying to ensure some IntegerField values are nonnegative.

I have created a class like so (in the models file):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    #solution block attempts are inserted here
```

I want to ensure views and likes are nonnegative.  The test function is:

```
class CategoryMethodTests(TestCase):
    def test_enusre_views_are_positive(self):
        """
        ensure_views_are_positive should result 
        True for Categories where view are zero or positive
        """
        cat = Category(name='test', views=-1, likes=0)
        cat.save()
        self.assertEqual((cat.views >= 0), True)
```

I have tried the following solutions, inserted at the comment line in the Category class, with errors posted corresponding to each:

First attempt:

```
if views < 0:
    views = 0



TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'IntegerField' and  'int'
```

Second attempt:

```
if int(views) < 0:
    views = 0

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'IntegerField'
```

Third attempt:

```
@property 
    def ensure_views_are_positive(self):
        if self.views < 0:
            views = 0
            return views
```

This does not get any error message, but fails testing with:

```
AsssertionError: False != True
```

Probably because I am not calling the function anywhere.  I am not really sure where to call it (and would prefer it be automated in the class).

I feel like there must be a simple way to convert IntegerField data to int so that it can be worked with in functions / testing.  Is there a way to make the simple "if" statements work?  (If so, how?)  Or is an alternative needed?  (If so, what?)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use PositiveIntegerField? See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield

Comment: Good idea and I admit I hadn't tried it, but even with the fields changed to PositiveIntegerField it's failing the test.  (Maybe has something to do with how testing is handled?)

Comment: I don't get what is `views` in your first and second attempts. Shouldn't it be `cat.views`?

Comment: No, the attempts go into the commented line in the class category block, not the test script.